# How to use tf.repeat and another built-in highlevel funcs on Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-datasets

I want to do something like this code of NER task which will align WordPieces of word with tag of this word:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tokens = tf.ragged.constant([[4], [2, 5, 9]], dtype=tf.int32)
tags = tf.ragged.constant([3, 5], dtype=tf.int32)

flat_tokens = tf.reshape(tokens, [-1])
duplicated_tags = tf.repeat(tags, [tf.shape(tok)[0] for tok in tokens])

print(flat_tokens.numpy())  # -> [4 2 5 9]
print(duplicated_tags.numpy())  # -> [3 5 5 5]
```

But with input of `tokens` and `tags` to `tf.repeat` as datasets which should be outputs of `TextLineDataset`. Are any minimalistic ways to do it?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example of what you want using tf.data.Dataset

Comment: Yes, of course. For example like this https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kW2oHxLUohnJ3I3dtYcUXF075566cDLO?usp=sharing